# How to make the Priority column appear in Chrome Dev tools's Network tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to see this column, I can see it here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization

[image]

But I can't see it inside my Chrome Dev tools's Network tab. My Chrome is version 63.0, so pretty recent I think.

Comment: I was going to raise a ticket against the doc that it needs to explain how to do this, but it actually already does, in the Figure 1 description.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to press `F12` and then click on the `Network` tab...then  right click on any header, like `Time` or `Status`, and then from the dropdown menu, select `Priority`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [matthewhorne.me](https://matthewhorne.me/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/enable-protocol-tab-in-chrome-dev-tools.png))</sub>

Comment: Feeling silly, never tried to adjust the columns this way. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just right click on one of the headers like `Name` or `Status` and select `Priority` from the menu.